# How to call SOAP API through SOAP client in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

I am getting successfully response of the SOAP API by the some tools like SoapUI.
 I am working on the deltek API.

Following is the code format which i am using in SoapUI

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:del="http://tempuri.org/Deltek.Vision.WebServiceAPI.Server/DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebService">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <del:GetSchema>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <del:ConnInfoXML><![CDATA[<VisionConnInfo>
<databaseDescription>Example_Test (TEST_001)</databaseDescription>
<userName>test</userName>
<userPassword>test123</userPassword>
<integratedSecurity>Y</integratedSecurity>
</VisionConnInfo>]]> </del:ConnInfoXML>

         <!--Optional:-->
         <del:InfoCenter><![CDATA[User]]></del:InfoCenter>
      </del:GetSchema>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But when i am calling the API through the SOAP client in php. I am getting this error :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetSchemaResult] => ErrLoginValInvalid login. Please change the username or password and try again.Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: sGetSchema.validateVisionLogin.VisionWSUtil.ValidateVisionLogin
)
```

Following is my PHPcode :

```
$apiURL = 'http://example.com/Vision/VisionWS.asmx?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($apiURL, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1));

$conninfo = array(
           'ConnInfoXML' => array(
             'VisionConnInfo' => array(
               "databaseDescription"  => 'Example_Test (TEST_001)',
               "userName" => "test", 
               "userPassword" => 'test123',
               "integratedSecurity" => "Y"   
               )
            )
          );

$userinfo  = array('InfoCenter' => 'User');

try {

    $result = $client->GetSchema($conninfo, $userinfo);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    print_r($fault);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Please suggest? where am I in making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully on the request, you can see that the element `del:ConnInfoXML` contains a string.

To make it work, you have to set the `ConnInfoXML` as string too:

```
'ConnInfoXML' => '<VisionConnInfo>...</VisionConnInfo>';
```

When creating the string programmatically, be sure to escape the values, so the resulting XML is valid.